# In marketing experiment, can we determine the effect customer state has on response?

Tags: experiment-design, blocking

We have the goal of determining whether an email campaign has an impact on the amount of product that customers purchase. We have customers from several states but much more from some states than others. Customers from some states do in general buy more than customers from others.

Suppose we randomly assign 10% of the customers to the control group (they will not receive the email). Are we going to be able to determine what effect state has on customer response? Is there some obvious way this experiment should be analyzed?

Comment: You've told us about the control group, but we know nothing about your experimental group(s).

Comment: StatsStudent, the control group is identical in composition to the experimental group, except they will not receive the email, whereas everyone in the experimental group will receive the email. Does this help?

Comment: Are you familiar with linear regression?

Comment: You'll want to use some sort of propensity score analysis here since you can't randomly assign people to states.  Search CV here for causal inference or propensity score analysis or matching.

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with linear regression and understand that I can just fit a linear model relating a flag variable for the treatment and each state from which we have customers to the response variable.

Comment: I'm assuming from your question too that the experiment has already been conducted?

Comment: I will look into the propensity score stuff that you mentioned. But, technically, it hasn't happened yet. Soon, though.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Linear regression applies to quantitative date. States are a categorical variable.

Comment: An expansion on my response to @DimitriyV.Masterov because I tried to create a new line, not submit my response. Adding : But in every resource that I consult about experimental design, the experiments all seem to require that the same number of samples are from block i as are from block j, which wouldn't apply here if states are the blocking variable. So this has made it more difficult for me to understand how best to analyze the experiment.

Comment: If the experiment has not happened yet, that you may consider randomly assigning people from each state to control and to experiment. I'm not sure I understand @Accumulation's comment.  A regression analysis could certainly be appropriate in this case.  The OP should tell us what the response variable is though.  Is it just a 1 (purchase) vs. 0 (no purchase)?

Comment: @StatsStudent Would there be utility in sampling more customers from certain states? Or do you have in mind the same sample percentage applied to each state to ensure that no one state is represented more than it should be based on our overall customer composition? E.g. make sure exactly 10% of the customers in each state are put into the control group. The response variable is "number of items purchased."

Comment: If you didn't stratify on states during your randomization, there is no guarantee you'd get a sample (or one of sufficient size) from states of interest.  What if you got an unlucky sample with no one from Wyoming in the control group?  In addition, depending on how you intend to carry out the analysis, the sample sizes can alter your statistical power.

Comment: I haven't locked in our random sample yet and can definitely stratify on state. Some states have much less customers than others. Would it make sense to put a larger percentage of these customers in the control group?

Comment: The current control group size, 10%, was calculated as the minimum control group  size  to achieve certain values of alpha and beta based on completely random assignment of our entire population of customers (ignoring the question of state effects altogether)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a *sufficient* amount of user-level data with user-level randomized campaign assignment $T_i$, you can fit a simple linear least squares model that looks like:

$$y_i = \alpha + \beta \cdot T_i + \sum_{s=1}^{50} \delta_{s}\cdot s_i + \sum_{s=1}^{50} \gamma_{s}\cdot s_i \cdot T_i+\varepsilon_i,$$

where $s_i$ is a binary indicator for customer location. The interaction coefficients $\gamma$s will tell you if the treatment effect varies by state. I am assuming that DC (or some other state) is the reference category. The $\delta$s will take into account if customers in different states have heterogeneous spending patterns.

You can also go a more sophisticated version of this analysis using a [causal forrest](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04342) approach that will do some variable selection for you and decompose the overall effect into weighted state-specific ones.

Comment: I actually really like your response, including the link. But I am still unclear on how to make this analysis more like a classical analysis of experiments, where they talk about false positives and false negatives, etc. Is there any way to plan for the sample sizes/control group sizes necessary to achieve certain values for alpha and beta of the treatment effect?

Comment: Looking at p-values, coefficient magnitude, and standard errors/CIs would be the right approach. You are effectively comparing a whole bunch of (adjusted) means here, so this is very much like an experimental analysis that you are used to. You might want to adjust your alpha threshold down to reflect. If you don't have enough data, the SEs for that state and treatment interaction will be wide to reflect the limited data. There are also tools that can help you design a more sophisticated sampling approach, but this is somewhat advanced and best split out into a separate question.